# Set Transactional Route for twilio api

Tags: twilio, authy

How can I set transactional route to send OTP message?

I am using this: 
http://docs.authy.com/phone_verification.html

Comment: Hi, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio/Authy. What do you mean exactly? What code are you using right now and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How can I use Twilio Alpha sender id in Authy?